# Modify dataframe with a given condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | data 1 |  |
| Val B | data 2 | data 6 |
| Val B | data 3 | data |
| A2 | data 4 | data |
| Val B | data 5 | data 7 |

In the first column(col1), if ValB is found, just below the a cell, that starts with 'A', replace the only the ValB cell with the above cell element (that starts with A) retaining other values in the row of ValB. And ignore other 'Val B' rows if they are not below a cell that starts with A.

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | data 2 | data 6 |
| A2 | data 5 | data 7 |

Result

I want the result like this. Using python

Comment: One question - is necessary after `A`startswith rows test for `Val B` value?

Comment: Yes, "df = df.shift(-1)[df['col1'].str.startswith('A')].assign(col1 = df['col1'])" this worked, thank you Jezrael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need one row after match condition by [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with replace `col1` by original DataFrame use:

```
df = df.shift(-1)[df['col1'].str.startswith('A')].assign(col1 = df['col1'])
print (df)
  col1    col2    col3
0   A1  data 2  data 6
3   A2  data 5  data 7
```

Another idea is shifting only `col1` and then filter by condition in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].shift()
df = df[df['col1'].str.startswith('A', na=False)]
print (df)
  col1    col2    col3
1   A1  data 2  data 6
4   A2  data 5  data 7
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
data = [['A1', 'data 1', None], 
        ['Val B', 'data 2', 'data 6'], 
        ['Val B', 'data 3', 'data'], 
        ['A2', 'data 4', 'data'], 
        ['Val B', 'data 5', 'data 7'], 
        ['A3', 'data 6', 'data 8'], 
        ['A4', 'data 9', 'data 9']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
```

`df`

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   A1      data 1  None
1   Val B   data 2  data 6
2   Val B   data 3  data
3   A2      data 4  data
4   Val B   data 5  data 7
5   A3      data 6  data 8
6   A4      data 9  data 9
```

**Code**

```
s = df['col1'].mask(df['col1'].eq('Val B')).ffill()
df.assign(col1=s).groupby('col1').head(2).groupby('col1').tail(1)
```

output:

```
  col1  col2    col3
1   A1  data 2  data 6
4   A2  data 5  data 7
5   A3  data 6  data 8
6   A4  data 9  data 9
```

I think there may be cases where 'Val B' does not exist under A. so i make example and code.